# ActiveMQ queue traffic monitoring

Tags: performance, activemq-classic, monitoring, performance-testing

I read in ActiveMQ page, using JMX we can monitor queues in activemq. Is it possible to plot the graphs of messages count vs time, basically rate at which messages are arriving at queue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can monitor the values, you can plot it. If you want something out of the box, you can download Hawt.io and connect to AMQ. There is a chart feature that allows plotting various values.